# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite

I have added sqlite jar in lib folder into project and i also added into build path but still i'm getting `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC"` exception.

here is conection code.

```
try {
    String path = OsSpecificseperator.getPath(Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL().getPath());
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + path+"configuration/tools/KidProject_Database");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("DB : Connection: " + e.getMessage());
    return;
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the application you're building. Just because it's in the *build* path doesn't mean it's available at *execution* time.

Comment: From where did you download the driver ?

Comment: @Noob UnChained: I had downloaded it long back so i don't remember from where i had downloaded.But at that time It has worked fine with other project.

Comment: no its Eclipse RCP application

Answer (score 1):

I would think that `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")` is expecting a class name.  It looks like you're providing it a package name.